# Game in iphone using Flash Lite

Tags: iphone, flash

Hai everyone, may I ask whether iphone can support .swf file or not? This is because I have developed a mini game using Adobe Flash Lite by using action script 2.0 and save as .fla file and export as .swf file. If can, can give me some guidances on how to import .swf to iphone. Thank a lot.:)

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone and other iOS devices cannot run Flash apps (at least not without being jailbroken first). See http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/ for Apple's official position on Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Somedays the iPhone can support flash, others it can not. It all depends how Apple are feeling at the moment...

Currently the only way to run flash on iPhone is to jailbreak it first.